# Temporarily enable exhaustive pylint messages in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Visual Studio Code by default has sensible pylint settings that limits the number of pylint messages that are output.

Is there any way to easily trigger a "pylint run" including the tests that are disabled by vscode by default either on all modules or on an individual module without messing with the vscode settings every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to temporarily flip the linting cap for just a single lint check.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling that this was the case but it is nice to have it confirmed so I can stop looking.